# Conditional statement, "unary operator expected"

Tags: scripting

I am having a problem with an example script that is given in the textbook 'Unix and System Administration Handbook'.  The script is below... I am receiving an error that states `logscript: line 8: [: 1: unary operator expected`.

```
# The log level is set in the global variable LOG_LEVEL. The choices
# are, from most to least severe.  Error, Warning, Info, and Debug.

function logMsg {
    message_level=$1
    message_itself=$2

    if [ $message_level -le $LOG_LEVEL ]; then
            case $message_level in
                    0) message_level_text="Error";;
                    1) message_level_text="Warning";;
                    2) message_level_text="Info";;
                    3)message_level_text="Debug";;
                    *) message_level_text="Other"
    esac
    echo "${message_level_text}: $message_itself"
    fi
}


# Main program starts here
logMsg $1 $2
```

Any ideas as to why this error is showing up?

Comment: Quote the variables i.e. use `if [ "$message_level" -le "$LOG_LEVEL" ]` ..check whether `echo "$LOG_LEVEL"`  returns anything or not..

Comment: `$LOG_LEVEL` is not returning any value.  I believe that the text mentions that, if `LOG_LEVEL` is set within the current bash session then the script will be able to reference it.  Is this not right?

Comment: When asking this sort of question, you need to include your operating system, your shell, and the way you are launching the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is because `LOG_LEVEL` is not defined. You haven't given us any information at all about how you're running this function (nor what shell you are using or what operating system) but the error will go away if `LOG_LEVEL` is set.

For example:

```
$ foo=""; [ 1 -le $foo ] && echo yes
bash: [: 1: unary operator expected
```

While, if `$foo` is set:

```
$ foo="1"; [ 1 -le $foo ] && echo yes
yes
```

Comment: Thanks, I would upvote, but not enough rep.

Comment: @DavidJhoo no worries, accepting an answer is the way to say thanks on the SE sites. Welcome aboard!

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, please ensure your variable `LOG_LEVEL` is set, and call your script with an integer as the first argument (since the `if` is about to compare integers). Something like:

```
export LOG_LEVEL=3
./my_script 2 AnyMessage
```

Comment: I got it sorted it.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this:

```
if [[ $message_level -le $LOG_LEVEL ]]
```

Comment: that won't make any difference - see the accepted answer for the real problem