# -eq: unary operator expected, shell argument parsing

Tags: bash, shell, test

I am getting this error while comparing shell argument to a string. If the code look like this:

```
online=true
if [ "$2" -eq '-o' ]
then
    online=false
fi
echo $online
```

Then for e.g. input I am getting those results:

```
$ ./currency.sh 2 -o
./currency.sh: line 13: [: -o: integer expression expected
true
```

Comment: `-eq` is an arithmetic test operator - for string comparison, use `=`

Comment: Thank you. I'm not used to bash, Ruby is all I need for shell usually :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional statement, "unary operator expected"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192099/conditional-statement-unary-operator-expected)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

> ```
> if [ "$2" -eq '-o' ]
> ```

You have used arithmetic operator `-eq` which takes the second argument as a number.

Naturally, it fails for that reason alone.

---

## When comparing strings, you can use [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) `=` operator:

```
if [ "$2" = '-o' ]
```

Note, that this version should work in all shells, as it is defined by [POSIX (Portable Operating System Interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

## If you want [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))-specific version:

```
if [[ "$2" == '-o' ]]
```

Note, that this version will work in only [Bash (Bourne-again shell)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) and alike.

---

**In contrast, double brackets `[[ .. ]]` and `==` operator are both defined in [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) only and will not work in other shells.**

Comment: Thank you! Cold you explain in detail, why do you use double '[' around statement? I have tried both singular and double version of this and both works.